# What is the difference between DOMXPath::evaluate and DOMXPath::query?

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domxpath, evaluate

Trying to decide which is more appropriate for my use case...

After comparing the documentation for these methods, my vague understanding is [`evaluate`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.evaluate.php) returns a typed result but [`query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) doesn't. Furthermore, the [`query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) example includes looping through many results but the [`evaluate`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.evaluate.php) example assumes a single typed result.

Still not much the wiser! Could anyone explain (in as close as possible to layman's terms) when you would use one or the other - e.g. will the multiple/single results mentioned above always be the case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

DOMXPath::query() supports only expressions that return a node list. DOMXPath::evaluate() supports all valid expressions. The official method is named evaluate(), too: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-XPath/xpath.html#XPathEvaluator

Select all `p` elements inside a `div`: `//div//p`

Select all `href` attributes in `a` elements the current document: `//a/@href`

You can use the `string()` function to cast the first element of a node list to a string. This will not work with DOMXpath::query().

Select the title text of a document: `string(/html/head/title)`

There are other function and operators that will change the result type of an expression. But it is always unambiguous. You will always know what type the result is.

Comment: I miss this information from the PHP manual of [DOMXPath::query()](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) and [DOMXPath::evaluate()](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.evaluate.php)

Answer (score 7):

`query` will return a `DOMNodeList` regardless of your actual XPath expression. This suggests that you don't know what the result may be. So you can iterate over the list and check the [node type](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodetype) of the nodes and do something based on the type.

But `query` is not limited to this use case. You can still use this when you know what type you will get. It may be more readable in the future what you wanted to achieve and therefore easier to maintain.

`evaluate` on the other hand gives you exactly the type that you select. As the examples point out:

```
$xpath->evaluate("1 = 0"); // FALSE
$xpath->evaluate("string(1 = 0)"); // "false"
```

As it turns out selecting attributes `//div/@id` or text nodes `//div/text()` still yields `DOMNodeList` instead of strings. So the potential use cases are limited. You would have to enclose them in `string`: `string(//div/@id)` or text nodes `string(//div/text())`.

The main advantage of `evaluate` is that you can get strings out of your `DOMDocument` with fewer lines of code. Otherwise it will produce the same output as `query`.

[ThW's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23796070/1816580) is right that some expressions will not work with `query`:

```
$xpath->query("string(//div/@id)") // DOMNodeList of length 0
$xpath->evaluate("string(//div/@id)") // string with the found id
```