# Why does DOMXPath->evaluate() not return a typed result?

Tags: php, dom

Here is my code:

```
$label = $xpath->evaluate('./strong[1]/text()[1]', $div)->item(0);
$value = $xpath->evaluate('./span[1]/text()[1]', $div)->item(0);
```

Both of these return a string. However, if I remove the `->item(0)` then it will return a DOMNodeList.

This appears to not follow PHP's documentation of `DOMXPath::evaluate` which states:

> Executes the given XPath expression and returns a typed result if possible.

Is there a way to change the query in `evaluate()` to directly get the text result I am seeking?

Comment: What type other than string would you expect _text result_ to be?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23793816/what-is-the-difference-between-domxpathevaluate-and-domxpathquery?rq=1

Comment: It is returning DOMNodeList (without `item(0)`), I am hoping for a string.